# Best practice for storing many long SQL queries in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am developing applications with Delphi XE. I have many long SQL queries and I don't want to store them in code like below, because this method reduces code readability:

```
CONST_SQL1 = 'SELECT ... FROM ..'#13#10 + 'WHERE ...';
```

Maybe creating a DataModule and storing the SQL queries in the Memo components can be an alternative option. This way the SQL queries will have more readability rather than the method above but in this way, I have to add many Memo components in the DataModule like Memo_SQL1, Memo_SQL2, Memo_SQL3, ...

Also I don't want to store these SQL queries in separate files or in a database.

Is there a single component that I can store all these SQL queries inside or what is your best practice for this case?

Comment: I usually use query components on a data module which makes editing and in some cases testing from inside the IDE easy. Don't have to instance the data module in the program - just include the unit and you can access the query text to use elsewhere (ex Unit2.DataModule2.FDQuery1.SQL;).

Comment: Personally, i prefer to save all query used in my application in separate structured file like JSON

Comment: "_I don't want to store these SQL queries ... in a database_" - it would miss the point if you need SQL to access your SQL. Storing all queries in one and the same text file is not really a problem if you add a tiny bit of programming logic to read in the file.

Comment: What's wrong with storing the queries in the database as stored procedures? Plus, you get a performance boost when executing the queries.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for all of your comments. On my project I prefer only one file and that is the program's EXE. Since I don't want any other separate files, I prefer the SQL queries to be stored in an EXE resource. Since SQL queries are changing so often and storing the SQL queries in the database needs additional insert efforts, I don't prefer to store them in the database.

I tried to develop the most basic and helpful method for my needs. In this method, all SQL queries are being stored in an EXE resource as a single XML file format. I am sharing below if this method can help any other people.

- **SQLQueries.rc**:

  ```text
  SQLQueries RCDATA SQLQueries.xml
  ```
- **SQLQueries.xml** (in UTF-8):

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <SQLQueries>
      <SQLQuery SQLQueryName="SQL1">
          SELECT
              *
          FROM
              TABLE1
          WHERE
              1 = 1
      </SQLQuery>
      <SQLQuery SQLQueryName="SQL2">
          SELECT
              *
          FROM
              TABLE2
          WHERE
              2 = 2
      </SQLQuery>
  </SQLQueries>
  ```
- **Project1.dpr**:

  ```pas
  program Project1;

  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

  {$R Project1.res} // program's default res file storing the icon, version info, etc..

  {$R 'SQLQueries.res' 'SQLQueries.rc'} // add this line. if not SQLQueries.res automatically created after compile, try dragging and dropping SQLQueries.rc file to the project.

  uses
    Windows, Classes, XMLDoc, XMLIntf, Generics.Collections, ActiveX;

  var
    SQLDictionary: TDictionary<string,string>;

  procedure LoadGetSQLQueries;
  var
    ResourceStream: TResourceStream;
    XMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
    XMLNode: IXMLNode;
    i: Integer;
  begin
    ResourceStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'SQLQUERIES', RT_RCDATA);
    try
      XMLDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
      try
        XMLDocument.LoadFromStream(ResourceStream);
        for i := 0 to XMLDocument.ChildNodes['SQLQueries'].ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
        begin
          XMLNode := XMLDocument.ChildNodes['SQLQueries'].ChildNodes[i];
          SQLDictionary.AddOrSetValue(XMLNode.Attributes['SQLQueryName'], XMLNode.Text);
        end;
      finally
        XMLDocument := nil;
      end;
    finally
      ResourceStream.Free;
    end;
  end;

  begin
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      SQLDictionary := TDictionary<string,string>.Create;
      try
        LoadGetSQLQueries;
        Writeln(SQLDictionary['SQL1']);
        Readln;
      finally
        SQLDictionary.Free;
      end;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
  end.
  ```
- Compiled EXE with my resource named `SQLQueries` and its content:

  [image: EXE resources]
- The program's output of `Writeln(SQLDictionary['SQL1'])` verifies that the SQL query has been read successfully by `XMLDocument.LoadFromStream(ResourceStream)`:

  [image: program's console output]

Comment: Please crop screenshots to relevant portions - maximized windows with large blank areas just demonstrating your desktop resolution help nobody.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes, I fixed the screenshots.

Comment: I'm still a little confused how an XML file makes this more readable then a constant or INC file using 'MultiPaste'?

Comment: @FredS When having many SQL queries and they are so long and they are changing so often, this method is more useful for me rather than splitting strings with + and #13#10

Comment: I get your point, over the years I've tried many things and essentially ended up using an inc file opened in Notepad++ with Column editing. Take any SQL paste it below a constant then use ALT+Mouse to prefix as string ('  ), select column at end and End string ( ' + ) . Linefeeds are optional but easy to enter this way: https://pastebin.com/9rcQxaW5

Comment: I'd avoid XML, because then I need to escape characters like `<` and `>` in my queries. Just text would have more advantages without being any more difficult to be read by the program (and not needing a whole XML interpreter at all). Strictly speaking the INI format could also fit with one query per section.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a single (text) resource file for each query. That makes it much easier to trace changes in your source code management system.

Add a subfolder in your project's directory for your SQL files and add them to a rc- file like:

```
SQL1               TEXT  .\SQL\SQL1.sql
SQL2               TEXT  .\SQL\SQL1.sql
```

Add that rc-file to the project and you can load the SQL text directly into the SQL member of a TQuery, just like

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}
{$R 'SQLQueries.res' 'SQLQueries.rc'}

uses
  Windows,
  Data.SqlExpr,
  Classes;

var
  ResourceStream: TResourceStream;
  Query: TSQLQuery;
begin
  ResourceStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'SQL1', 'TEXT');
  Query:= TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    Query.SQL.LoadFromStream(ResourceStream);
    Writeln(Query.SQL.Text);
    ReadLn;
  finally
    Query.Free;
    ResourceStream.free;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

A tip, you can use *views* on the database server, on your code in delphi you use `SELECT * FROM VW_CUSTOMER`, you always can modify the queries there, the plus side is that all changes in the logic are automatically reflected in all your instances of our EXE, the cons side is if your remove o add a column, if you add there must be an uprade of your exe to show the new column, if your remove or change the name of a column, you will have an exception where the query on that modified view is used.